# Error with igraph library

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to use the following R library: `iSubpathwayMiner` that requires the following packages: 
`graph`, `igraph`, `RBGL`. 
While running the string

```
graphList<-getMetabolicECECGraph()
```

that you can find in the vignette, the following Error I'm not able to manage occurs:

```
#    Error in if (get.vertex.attribute(graphList[[i]], "type", j - 1) %in%  : 
#      argument is of length zero
```

Can anyone help me at least to try to understand what does it means and how to manage it?

Thank you in advance

Best

Comment: The library `iSubpathwayMiner` was removed from CRAN due to unresolved errors and conflicts. Furthermore, the `graph` library is unavailable for the latest `R` version. Perhaps that error is due to the aforementioned conflicts. You also do not mention what `R` version and platform you are using. The error you posted most likely results from `graphList` (if it is populated) not having an attribute `type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that the argument of the `if` is `NULL`. This most likely arises because your graph does not have an attribute named `type`. There are errors and other unresolved conflicts with these libraries, so it is not possible to rule anything else out.

You can run this example in a R session

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(10)
g <- set.graph.attribute(g, "name", "RING")
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, "color", value=c("red", "green"))

get.vertex.attribute(g, "color")
#>[1] "red"   "green" "red"   "green" "red"   "green" "red"   "green" "red"   "green"

#Asking for an attribute that does not exist will return NULL
get.vertex.attribute(g, "day")
#>NULL

#And 
if(NULL){print(1)}
#>Error in if (NULL) { : argument is of length zero

#so
if(get.vertex.attribute(g, "day") %in% c("Mon","Tue","Wed")){print("doSomething")}
#>Error in if (get.vertex.attribute(g, "day") %in% c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed")) { : 
#argument is of length zero
```

In general, you should check that an argument of an `if` statement is not `NULL` by using something like `is.null()` beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much Rusan. I was simply typing the code reported in the vignette. in addiction the package is not compatible with the newest R version 3.1.1 so probably it is better not to use it anymore. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. Yes, always best to check packages are up to date and have passed the CRAN checks.